# How to send data to laravel echo websocket from client to server

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I am developing a Laravel app based on Websockets using `Laravel Echo`.

Everything works fine on the server side, when I send data (through the visual interface of `Laravel-Websockets` from the browser) they appear in real time in the browser console.

Such that: (client side)

```
Echo.channel('testchannel')
    .listen('TestEvent', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
```

But then I also want to be able to send data from the client side to the server (as it would be done with the [Websocket:send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send) method) and for this I use the following line of code:

```
Echo.connector.socket.emit('App/Events/TestEvent', 'testchannel', {"message":"Hello World"});
```

However, the following error appears in the browser console:

`TypeError: Echo.connector.socket is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, I think it is better to post your data to your backend and broadcast it in your controller.

```php
broadcast(new App/Events/TestEvent())->toOthers();
```

However, this is my idea. if there is a better solution i would like to benefit.

Comment: This answer is not related to the question !!